# How to get Max Date in Linq?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

How can i compare Max of `i.Endate` and compare against `request.lastMonthBilled.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` in the following linq?

```
var invoiceEndDate = Context.Invoices.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(i => i.EndDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") == request.lastMonthBilled.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") )
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need `ToString` ? What is "Max of `i.Endate`"?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. Looks like you're looking for a way to truncate datetimes and get the maximum value of datetimes of one specific day. Is that correct? Also, what flavor of LINQ is this? Which ORM?

Comment: What do you mean by "Max of `i.EndDate`? By the looks of your code, it looks like you want to select invoices which the end date month equals the request month.

Comment: @JeffMercado I have multiple EndDate of the same project, i want to compare `request.lastMonthBilled.Date` the last end Date

Comment: Multiple? What determines "Multiple?" `Context.Invoices` is all invoices. Do you want the max of invoices by a particular user? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @JeffMercado i think i was confused you right, I feel bad Craig Delete the answer

Comment: @Rob So, what's the problem with the query statement you provided, what's your exepted result. Maybe you can illustrate combined with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell us the type of property EndDate. I assume it is a DateTime:

```
class Invoice
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Some databases tend to save DateTimes as strings, some do it in some numeric format. The important part is: can your entity framework version compare DateTimes?

```
var newestIinvoice = dbContext.Invoices
    .OrderByDescending(invoice => invoice.EndDate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If your EndDate is a string, you can't order it like this. There are several solutions possible, depending on the database functionality that you have:

- Convert the EndDate into format "yyyyMMdd" and orderByDescending text
- Get the Year / Month / Date and order:

  var newestIinvoice = dbContext.Invoices
  .OrderByDescending(invoice => invoice.EndDate.Year)
  .ThenByDescending(invoice => invoice.EndDate.Month)
  .ThenBy(invoice => invoice.EndDate.Date)
  .FirstOrDefault();